How to return used context to answer using Langchain in Python
I have built a RAG system like this:
loader = PyPDFLoader(pdf_file_name)
raw_documents = loader.load()

text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=1000, chunk_overlap=200)
documents = text_splitter.split_documents(raw_documents)
print(documents[-1])

Document(
   metadata={'source': '/Appraisal.pdf', 'page': 37},
   page_content='File No.\nProperty Address\nCity County State Zip Code\nClient10828\nBorrower or Owner John Smith & Kitty Smith\n29 Dream St\nDreamTown SC 99999\nSouthern First Bank\nBB Appraisals, LLC'
)

compressor = CohereRerank(
    top_n=top_n,
    model="rerank-english-v3.0",
    cohere_api_key=""
)

retriever = vectorstore.as_retriever(
    search_type="similarity", 
    search_kwargs={"k": top_n}
)

compression_retriever = ContextualCompressionRetriever(
    base_compressor=compressor, base_retriever=retriever
)

def format_docs(docs):
    return "\n\n".join(doc.page_content for doc in docs)

response_schemas = [
    ResponseSchema(name="price", description="Price", type="float"),
    ResponseSchema(name="unit", description="Unit", type="int"),
]
output_parser = StructuredOutputParser.from_response_schemas(response_schemas)

rag_prompt = PromptTemplate(
    input_variables=["context","question"],
    template=template,
    partial_variables={"format_instructions": output_parser.get_format_instructions()},
)

rag_chain = (
    {"context": compression_retriever | format_docs, "question": RunnablePassthrough()}
    | rag_prompt
    | llm
    | output_parser
)

query = "What is the price? How many units?"

response = rag_chain.invoke(query, config={"configurable": {"session_id": "abc123"}},)

But then my response is a JSON with my price and unit as keys only. And I would like to be able to have a "context" variable that stores the paragraphs used in my document that the algo relied upon to answer the questions.
Any idea how I could do that please?

you want the llm to point you to where the information was found right?

Yes that's exactly what i'd like to do

you should delete your api_key asap.

There are two ways to do this

For pictorial rep. of the information, as to which document the LLM used,  You would need to visit langchain_smith, you must also understand some methodologies in RAG - LIKE RAG-FUSION, this will help you create a RAG-FUSION used by the llm to get the documents it used to retrieve the information.

I am not sure about this, but you can try this function, pipe it with your compression_retriever chain. The idea of this function is for you to pass it along with the llm or the retriever as the case maybe, so as to make retrieving the docs easier


def unique_union_of_documents(docs: list) -> list[Any]:
    """
    Get the unique union of the documents
    Args:
    docs: The documents to be processed

    Returns:
    list: The unique union of the documents"""

    doc_news = [json.dumps(doc.page_content) for _ in docs]
    # find the unique union of the documents
    unique_union = list(set(doc_news))

    return [json.loads(doc) for doc in unique_union]

You can now call this function after your variable response

so I added your function like this {"context": compression_retriever | get_unique_union_of_documents | format_docs, "question": RunnablePassthrough()} but it gives AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'page_content'

what is the compression_retriever? You would have to show me that. you also have to provide how you are retrieving data , are you using vectordb?

Sorry, I should have added my format_docs function before ! Cause it returns a string. And I added my compression_retriever

ok can you try using the function i provided instead of format_docs?

I get "AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'page_content'" coming from "doc_news = [json.dumps(doc.page_content) for sublist in docs for doc in sublist]"

@NicolasREY no worries so we are on the same page so you just want to have a variable called context, which can be passed to your "rag_chain"?

In the end, I would like a variable context that is a list of all the "useful" paragraphs in the documents that were used to answer the questions. Am I being clear ?

@NicolasREY yeah crystal! so have you tried the updated function. the function should give you the documents used by the llm, but the function has to be tailored to how your documents are structured, by passing it along with your llm, it is easier to retrieve. please a snippet of how your data is structured?

I've updated the code. For now i am using PyPDFLoader, but I'd like to use llamaParse later I think. But langchain has an issue with UnstructuredMarkdownLoader for now

Documents is list of 132 langchain_core.documents.base.Document.

apologies can you update in your question and format it so it is clearer thanks.

No worry, I just updated the question. is it enough element or you need more example of documents ?

can you please format as a code? the docs are not quite clear

Sorry, I didn't get it. Done.

I put it as a string then

before you had it good before with the Document=({result}) <-  just put this in a new line in your question  , so I can pass the documents easily inside my function, I cant loop through the result, look at your "response_schemas" for example it is ok, I can copy it but dont understand the docs provided

Is it better like this ?

@NicolasREY  awesome so I have updated the code let me know how that goes, if you pass your Documents into the function I provided does it return all the results from the page_contents.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
